# ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (240,320,3) into shape (480,640,3)

Tags: python, numpy

I tried to "paste" resized images on original size black background to keep the image dimension, and I used following code. Note that ogirinal image size is (640, 480), and scale factor is 0.5 (i.e. resized image = (320, 240))

```
new_img_w = int(scale_factor * orig_img_w)
new_img_h = int(scale_factor * orig_img_h)
new_scaled_img = cv2.resize(image, (new_img_w, new_img_h))
canvas = np.zeros_like(image)
x_lim = int(min(new_img_w,1)*orig_img_w)
y_lim = int(min(new_img_h,1)*orig_img_h)
canvas[:y_lim,:x_lim,:] = new_scaled_img[:y_lim,:x_lim,:] #Error message this line
new_scaled_img = canvas
```

And got the error message in the title.
Could you help me to troubleshoot this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why are you multiplying the old and new dimensions to get the limits? This seems wrong to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the error occurs in

```
canvas[:y_lim,:x_lim,:] = new_scaled_img[:y_lim,:x_lim,:]
```

test

```
print(canvas[:y_lim,:x_lim,:].shape)
print(new_scaled_img[:y_lim,:x_lim,:].shape)
```

Looks like you have the wrong `y_lim` and `x_lim`.  If you are trying to copy `new_scaled_img` into a corner of `canvas`, I'd suggest getting those limits from

```
new_scaled_img.shape
```

In any case, you need to verify that the slicing dimensions make sense on both sides of the assignment.  Don't assume anything.  Verify!

Comment: I am trying to copy it into the center of the canvas... but still not sure why the error happened...

Comment: `min(new_img_w,1)*orig_img_w` is `orig_img_w`.  So `canvas[:y_lim,:x_lim,:]` is the **whole** `canvas` array.  You can't copy an array 1/4 that size into it!  Like said, get those slicing limits correct.  Both sides must match!

Comment: In both Python lists and arrays, slicing beyond the boundary doesn't raise an error, but it doesn't increase the size either.   `np.arange(10)[:20]` is still a 10 element array.

Comment: Oh, now I understand what you mean :) Thanks a lot for your help!